# Configuring AutoMapper without Generics

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I am trying to configure AutoMapper without using generics as I want to configure it at runtime.

I want to configure the SubstiteNulls method and be able to do the equivalent of:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Dest>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Value, opt => opt.NullSubstitute("Other Value"));
```

But I can't figure out how to do this.  You can pass they Type objects into the `CreateMap` factory method but when you use the `ForMember` method, the `opt` object does not contain the `NullSubstitute` method and I imagine this is due to the lack of generic that I am using here.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

### Update

These are the options that I am getting:

[image]

Comment: So which options have you choose eventually?

Answer (score 3):

Currently the `NullSubstitute` configuration is not available on the `IMappingExpression` interface which is used when you are using the non generic version of `CreateMap`.

There is no limitation which is preventing Automapper to have this method on the `IMappingExpression` so currently this is just not supported.

You have three options:

- Create an [issue on Github](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues) and wait until it is implemented
- Fork the project and implement the method yourself. It is very easy you can use the [generic version](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/develop/src/AutoMapper/Internal/MappingExpression.cs#L217-L220) as an example.
- Or if you want a quick but very dirty solution. With reflection you can get the underlaying `PropertyMap` from the configuration and call the `SetNullSubstitute` method on it:

  ```
  Mapper.CreateMap(typeof(Source), typeof(Dest))
      .ForMember("Value", opt =>
          {
              FieldInfo fieldInfo = opt.GetType().GetField("_propertyMap",
                  BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
              var propertyMap = (PropertyMap) fieldInfo.GetValue(opt);
              propertyMap.SetNullSubstitute("Null Value");
      });
  ```

Comment: Please choose option #1 or #2 :)